# Copy data from one sheet to another by multiple criteria in the Column

Tags: excel

I have a Sheet with data and another contains filter words in the field.
My code copy data from Sheet "Data" to Sheet2 on criteria words E2:E10 in the SheetFilt. Now it works only with one criteria in E2 Cell. How can I use range E2:E10 (or Name of the range)

```
Sub Copy()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)
For i = 2 To LastRow
If InStr(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "H"), Sheets("SheetFilt").Range("E2")) <> 0 Then
Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I'd like to use range E2:E10 instead of E2, something like this (but this ends with error)

```
If InStr(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "H"), Sheets("SheetFilt").Range("E2:E10")) <> 0
```

How can I realize it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim i, j, LastRow as Long

LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear

Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1).Value

For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 2 to 10
        If InStr(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 8), Sheets("SheetFilt").Cells(j, 5)) <> 0 Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = _
                                      Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Value = 
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

If there is any bug, I am just trying to follow your "idea", just let me know if something is wrong.

Hope it helps

Comment: Can't debug :(, something wrong (may be my example.xls may help  https://1drv.ms/x/s!AgfvDQ65okq02wDRY-5cEwDbCTJS?e=KH0IhR  )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to David. Final working variant. (Note, there is no empty cells in Filter words range E2:E50, I use any symbol instead, like "~")

```
Sub Copy()
Dim i, LastRow
LastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear
Worksheets("Data").Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)
For i = 2 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To 50
If InStr(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "H"), Sheets("SheetFilt").Cells(j, "E")) <> 0 Then
Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Good job! Congratulations